# Convert java 1.8 to 1.6

Tags: java, json, java-stream, java-6

How can i convert it to java 1.6? Method .stream()  is unable in java 1.6.

```
final Optional<Entry<String, String>> mapping = cfg.getTypeMapping()
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith(jsonType + "|"))
                .findFirst();
```

Comment: ... why would you want to do that? just start using Java 8. Otherwise, rewrite the code in Java 6 compliant code

Comment: @Stultuske, that's exactly what he wants to do

Comment: @jhamon yah, I gathered that. the point is, that's a bad thing to do.

Comment: @Stultuske Instead of hyperfocus on what he should do you might want to hint him in the right direction? ... if Java is your thing offcourse ;-)

Comment: @leonard You might want add some trial code that shows in which direction you are thinking.. errors you encountered...etc. That shows effort and please finish the tour to understand how to improve your question even more.

Comment: @ZF007 if you consider going back to a no-longer-supported version, and getting rid of tons of bugfixes and security patches 'the right direction' ... I don't really.
This is also why I posted my response as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: @Stultuske Sound like you know your Java stuff. Can you guide him through the minefield? In the side line refer to parts of websites why its not preferred to downgrade at all. This question can make it to a nice wiki instead off being killed by a downvote frenzy. ( I as a triage reviewer want to learn too from topics I'm not an expert at.;-).

Comment: @ZF007 just because I commented in the line of "don't, it's a bad idea", doesn't mean I downvoted anything. Sure, I could guide him through what to do, but that has already been done, so it seems a bit pointless. GhostCat pretty much got it covered in his answer

Comment: @Stultuske ..wasn't showing during triage review. But yes I agree Ghostcat nailed it first ;-) Can't recall if I upped this type of issue during survey 2019. Anyway..have a good one. Me "out".

Comment: Thank all ! ...

Answer (score 6):

Let's have a quick look:

```
mapping = cfg.getTypeMapping()
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith(jsonType + "|"))
            .findFirst();
```

The above code probably fetches some sort of map, gets its entries, and iterates those, to stop on the first key that `startsWith(jsonType + "|")`.

That is all, and could easily be rewritten in old-school loop code.

But the actual challenge here is: `final Optional<Entry<String, String>>`: the class **Optional** was added to Java with Java 1.8.

There is **no** equivalent for it. So the whole of you code simply can **not** be rewritten for Java 1.6

The closest thing you could do: write that looping code, and if the loop finds something, return that result, otherwise return null. Alternatively, you could do this:

```
List<Entry<String, String>> firstMapping = Collections.emptyList(); 
for (Entry<String, String> entries = cfg.getTypeMapping().entrySet()) {
  if (entry.getKey().startsWith(jsonType + "|")) {
    firstMapping = Collections.singletonList(entry);
    break;
  }
} 
return firstMapping;
```

Alternatively, given the fact that the OP considers using `com.google.common.base.Optional`, you could do:

```
for (Entry<String, String> entries = cfg.getTypeMapping().entrySet()) {
  if (entry.getKey().startsWith(jsonType + "|")) {
    return Optional.of(entry);
  }
} 
return Optional.absent();
```

instead.

And of course, always remember: Java 6 is. One should avoid active development for it, even more so when one has to rely on other people to do the actual back porting work.

( disclaimer: my code samples are meant as detailed pseudo code inspiration, I did not run it through a compiler, it might contain typos or such )

Comment: Can't the OP use `targetCompatibility = '1.6'` for compilation and afterwards the contents of the class file could be decompiled using JD-GUI and from there the source code could be copied.

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha That doesn't help you. targetCompatibility **only** affects the source code syntax that is allowed and determines the magic number in the generated byte code. That byte code would **still** be using java.util.Optional which does not exist in Java 1.6. And you can't go in and easily add such missing classes.

Comment: Thank you so much, i'm an intern and this is my project which converts from json schema to xml schema. But i write it in java 1.8 and now i have to use it in system that written in java 1.6. The class Optional can be used from avro.shaded.com.google.common.base.Optional<Entry<String, String>> (i don't know it right or wrong). I keep trying to fix it. Thank you one more.
(Sorry if my English has mistakes. I'm not good at it =))).

Answer (score 1):

Streams almost always are convertible to loops. You can create a for loop, loop through each entry in the entry set, check if it matches your condition in the `filter`. If it does, break the loop immediately

```
Entry<String, String> result = null;
for (Entry<String, String> entry : cfg.getTypeMapping().entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().startsWith(jsonType + "|")) {
        result = entry;
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that instead of `Optional`, I used null to represent a "not found" value.

Comment: Thank you so much.